# $(\mathcal{X}^*)^{**}$ and $(\mathcal{X}^{**})^*$ are equal.

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, dual-spaces

Taken from Conway's A Course in Functional Analysis Chapter 3 Section 11 Problem 1:

Problem Statement: Show that $(\mathcal{X}^*)^{**}$ and $(\mathcal{X}^{**})^*$ are equal.

I wanted to see if my solution below was complete.

We show that these two sets include each other. Let our field be $\mathbb{F}$. Suppose that $x \in (\mathcal{X}^*)^{**}$. This is a linear map between linear maps, each from $\mathcal{X} \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$. Since $\mathcal{X}^{**}$ are elements in $\mathcal{X}$, it follows that $\mathcal{X}^*$ are maps from $\mathcal{X}\rightarrow \mathbb{F}$., it follows that  $x \in (\mathcal{X}^{**})^*$.
Conversely, let  $x \in (\mathcal{X}^{**})^*$. $x$ is then a linear functional from $\mathcal{X} \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$. From the description of $ (\mathcal{X}^*)^{**}$ in the previous paragraph, that $x \in (\mathcal{X}^*)^{**}$

Comment: This may be a silly question, but how is $^{**}$ defined here? I'm used to $X^{**}$ being shorthand for $(X^*)^*$ (i.e. the dual of the dual), in which case this question is trivial. How is $X^{**}$ defined in terms of $X$?

Comment: The book defines it this way: "If $x \in \mathcal{X}$ then $x$ defines an element $\hat{x}$ of $\mathcal{X}^{**}$, namely, define $\hat{x}: \mathcal{X}^* \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ by $\hat{x}(x^*) = x^*(x)$

Comment: @Will: This is not a definition of $X^{**}$.